# HTML 5 layout <section>

Tags: html

I have this website I am designing and I want to make it to the newest HTML5 standards.

The general layout is pretty simple as you can see in the image.[image: my html5 layout model]

So, since the content of #main is not always a blog article (more often it's a "static" page) which tag should I use?

Any other recommendations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `<section>`.
Those tags aren't limited to this usage.
You can, for example, have this kind of tree :

```
<header />
<section>
  <article>
    <header />
    <footer />
  </article>
</section>
<footer/>
```

`<section>` is here to help search engines to identify the most important divs, so show this one is important.

Comment: In better words, if anything you got in this `<div>` is related, so use `<section>`

Comment: Ok thanks. What is going to happen to the div tags? I feel like all my divs could be converted to sections...

Comment: Not really, `<div>` will still be used for smallest block, which doesn't need to be spotted by search engines. `<section>` is here for only important block. If the block content is just a list, some links or anything like that, it's not a section block.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at these two articles from [html5doctor.com](http://html5doctor.com):

- [Designing a blog with html5](http://html5doctor.com/designing-a-blog-with-html5/)
- [The section element](http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/)

In particular, the "designing a blog post" article describes a page layout almost exactly like the layout in your question. Two pertinent quotes regarding the main content area are:

> The `section` element represents a generic document or application section... The `section` element is not a generic container element. When an element is needed for styling purposes or as a convenience for scripting, authors are encouraged to use the `div` element instead.

and

> Rules of thumb for using `section`:
>
> - Don't use it just as hook for styling or scripting; that's a `div`
> - Don't use it if `article`, `aside` or `nav` is more appropriate
> - Don't use it unless there is naturally a heading at the start of the section

I suggest using an `article` for the main content. If you have multiple items in the main content and they thematically related *and* can be grouped under a common title then use a `section`; otherwise use a `div`.

Comment: See updated post: Please note: I no longer recommend wrapping the whole content area in a section element, and suggest that you use a div element. Read more about using section appropriately: http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/